# Finding out how two tables are connected by looking in a third

Tags: sql, oracle, having

I have a couple of tables:

```
boxes Table         ToysTable       Kitchen Table
boxId | ID          Name  | ID      Type   |  ID
-------------      --------------   -----------
1   | TOY1        Ball    | TOY1     Fork  | KIT1
1   | TOY2        Car     | TOY2     Knife | KIT2
1   | KIT1        Puzzle  | TOY3     Spoon | KIT3
2   | KIT2
```

I want to find what box contains my stuff.
So if I ask:
What box contains a fork and my car toy.
I want to get the Id of that box, in this case 1.

How would I do this ?

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11b0a/3/0

Edit:
Updated column name on kitchen to type.

Edit2:
Final solution became something like this (Thanks Gordon):

```
select b.boxid
from boxes b left join
     (select id, 'toy' type
      from toys t
      where t.name in ('Car', 'Fork')
      union all
      select id, 'kitchen' type
      from kitchen k
      where k.name in ('Car', 'Fork')
     ) tk
     on b.id = tk.id
group by b.boxid
having count(distinct tk.type) = 2;
```

Comment: How do you implement relations between tables? Have you got an foreign keys to ToysTable and Kitchen table?

Comment: The ID column in boxes table is a connection to either a Toy ID or a kitchen ID

Comment: No its oracle, cant get that sqlfiddle to work. Dont know how I save anything. It just turns up blank when i open it up in a new tab

Comment: I'm getting a blank SQL Fiddle, is the link valid?  Is there anything in your design that prevents the ID column in Toy from containing the same value as the ID column in Kitchen?  If this happens you would never be able to identify which value to return.  If at all possible I would recommend revisiting your table design.  Perhaps a box, item, itemtype and box item xref would work better here.

Comment: No the id's in toys can never be the same as in kitchen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, because the `id` could be to either table.  One solution is `group by` with a `union all`.  Here is a generic approach, assuming that the ids in the two reference table have different values:

```
select b.boxid
from boxes b left join
     (select id, name 
      from toys t
      union all
      select id, name
      from kitchen k
     ) tk
     on b.id = tk.id
group by b.boxid
having sum(case when tk.name = 'Car' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when tk.name = 'Fork' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Note:  In MySQL, I would write this query as:

```
select b.boxid
from boxes b left join
     (select id, name 
      from toys t
      where t.name in ('Car', 'Fork')
      union all
      select id, name
      from kitchen k
      where k.name in ('Car', 'Fork')
     ) tk
     on b.id = tk.id
group by b.boxid
having count(distinct name) = 2;
```

You could write it this way in any SQL dialect, actually.

Comment: @ViktorEriksson . . . The SQL Fiddle is correct.  There are no matches.  This version shows that it works:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ceac/1.

Comment: Back to work now and I have had a chance to look at this. First of all I might have been making the tables to simple. They dont have common column names except the ID column. I updated the fiddle with the kitchentable having type as column instead of name. Could you explain the last row in the sql, having count(distinct name) = 2. What does it mean and how will this work now when the columns have different names ?